# Firefox CSS transition fails in conjunction with jQuery prop() on placeholder

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

Got a weird one for you all.  I am using CSS transition to change length of input at same time as modifying placeholder attribute / property. For some reason it fails to animate in firefox.  Works fine in Chrome and Safari.  As demonstrated below, I can alter another property like "disabled" and everything is fine.  When I view this in firefox, `#input1` does not animate, while `#input2` is perfectly fine.  Any idea how to overcome this?

https://jsfiddle.net/shjw4ueh/1/

```js
$('#select').on('change', function () {
    if (this.value == 'short') {
        $('#input1').addClass('short').prop('placeholder', 'Type there...');
        $('#input2').addClass('short').prop('disabled',false);;
    } else {
        $('#input1').removeClass('short').prop('placeholder', 'Type here...');
        $('#input2').removeClass('short').prop('disabled',true);;
    }
});
```

```css
input {
    width: 200px;
    transition: width 1s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease 0s;
    margin: 5px;
}
input.short {
    width: 150px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
    <option value="long">Long</option>
    <option value="short">Short</option>
</select>
<br />
<input id="input1" placeholder="Type here..." />
<br />
<input id="input2" placeholder="Type here..." />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update `placeholder` property "correctly", you need to add `.blur()` at the end of `.prop` or `.attr` statement. And in this case you also need to call the `.addClass` and `.removeClass` after set `placeholder`.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#select').on('change', function () {
    if (this.value == 'short') {
        $('#input').prop('placeholder', 'Type there...').blur().addClass('short');
        $('#input2').addClass('short').prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
        $('#input').prop('placeholder', 'Type here...').blur().removeClass('short');
        $('#input2').removeClass('short').prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/shjw4ueh/4/

Comment: Wow.. thanks.  That's really weird.  I just chained it the same as in your edit.  Do you have an explanation as to why Mozilla wants a `blur()` event for this to work?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an explanation, but have the same issue some time ago and this was the solution.